# stdout.splitlines() drops the last line of stdout

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.9 and `subprocess.run` to get ping data.

Here is the snippet:

```py
out = subprocess.run(f"ping -c 1 -w 1 {ip_addr}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
print(out.stdout)  # Here I do get the last line with rtt

**Output is:**
*PING 10.0.2.5 (10.0.2.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
--- 10.0.2.5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.077/0.077/0.077/0.000 ms*

# the above gives a line with rtt

for line in out.stdout.splitlines():
    print(f'line = {line}') # This prints all lines but the last one with rtt

**Output is:**
line = PING 10.0.2.5 (10.0.2.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
line = 64 bytes from 10.0.2.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
line = 
line = --- 10.0.2.5 ping statistics ---
line = 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

#This however does not print the line with rtt.

Comment: Did you try to use `subprocess.STDOUT`?

Comment: What is displayed? Share the output so we can see the problem.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I see the rtt line.

Comment: Post the output before trying to make changes. I ran your code without a problem (after defining ip_addr).

Comment: Edit the question and post the ouptut there in a code block like your original script. Its hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update in the question. I don't have any idea why this happens. splitlines works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce the issue.

```py
import subprocess

ip_addr = "google.com"
out = subprocess.run(f"ping -c 1 {ip_addr}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
print(out.stdout)
print('\n'.join(out.stdout.splitlines()))
```

```
# from out.stdout
PING google.com (172.217.14.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=19.980 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 19.980/19.980/19.980/nan ms
```

```
# from out.stdout.splitlines
PING google.com (172.217.14.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.14.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=19.980 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 19.980/19.980/19.980/nan ms
```

However, something to note. I would avoid using shell=True in production systems, as it can lead to unexpected command injection. We don't know where this code is being executed or how ip_addr is obtained in your case, but rather safe than sorry!

```py
ip_addr = str(input("Enter the IP you want to ping: "))
command = "ping -c 1 " + ip_addr
out = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
print(out.stdout)
```

User could enter something like `google.com; whoami`. Instead, you should do:

```py
ip_addr = str(input("Enter the IP you want to ping: "))
out = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c 1", ip_addr], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
print(out.stdout)
```

Comment: this runs as a part of a bigger program.  when i put just that piece into a separate small program, it did work for both print cases. must be something with my logic elsewhere. sorry to bother you. thanks.